# How to create new array of objects with key entrie made from two keys of previous array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const users = [
      {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      },
      {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      },
       {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      }
  ];
```

I want to get new array of objects with these properties

```
const updatedUsersObject = [
    {
    fullName:"Name Last Name"
  },
  {
    fullName:"Name Last Name"
  },
   {
    fullName:"Name Last Name"
  }
]
```

I've tried with

```
const updatedUsersObject = users.map(user=>{
  return user.firstName+" "+user.lastName;
});
```

But that is only returning array of full names.

Comment: `return {fullName: user.firstName+" "+user.lastName}`

Comment: @Nick spooky, was just writing the same comment...

Comment: @Nick Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const users = [
      {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      },
      {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      },
       {
        firstName:"Name",
        lastName:"Last Name"
      }
  ];
  
  console.log(users.map(item => ({fullName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`})));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const updatedUsersObject = users.map(
    (user) => ({
        fullNameid: user.firstName+' '+user.lastName
    })
)
```